# matSort headers not sorting table at all

Tags: angular-material

- Live Demo: https://matsort-audionote.firebaseapp.com/ (click the "title" header)
- My code: https://github.com/AskYous/audio-note/commit/75c667f66ec4e15a5dbd460ec044938782d672a4

I'm having a difficult time getting sortable headers to work. I attached a live demo of my app having header sorting not working, as well as the code I used to implement this. When I click on a header, I get not response. No errors, no sorting, no feedback. I did the following:

1. Added `matSort` directive to the table.
2. Added `mat-sort-header` to each header.
3. Imported `MatSortModule` into `app.module.ts`.
4. Provided the `MatSort` directive to the table data source.

The headers are clickable, and they have toggling arrows, but the rows are not being sorted on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are initializing your datasource's sort as matSort before table is rendered in DOM (because of the *ngIf)

```
this.notes.sort = this.sort;
```

change this line

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="notes" *ngIf="notes.data" matSort>
```

to

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="notes" [hidden]="!notes.data" matSort>
```