# Problem sorting with matSort with API data

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material, mat-table

My mat-table is working fine, but when adding mat-sort following the official api documentation, it fails at the ngAfterViewInit with the following message

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined**

[First error screenshot .. Not sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnfZI.png)

The Data are displayed correctly from the api, I moved the code to the constructor of the component to only set this in the onInit : 
this.listData.sort = this.sort;

I imported the module in the app.module.

So Here is my 3 files :

Componenet.html

```
  <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="gender">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Gender</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.gender}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>First Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.firstname}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {PersonneService} from '../../shared/personne.service';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort} from '@angular/material';
import {Personne} from '../../personne';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personne-list',
  templateUrl: './personne-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personne-list.component.css']
})
export class PersonneListComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  personne: any = [];
  constructor(private service: PersonneService) {
    this.service.getPersonnes().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.personne = data;
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.personne);
    });
  }

  listData: MatTableDataSource<Personne>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['gender', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'ordertotal', 'actions'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log({SORT: this.sort});
    this.listData.sort = this.sort;
  }

}
```

Service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Personne} from '../personne';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonneService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    address: new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(8), Validators.required]),
    city: new FormControl(''),
    state: new FormControl(''),
    gender: new FormControl('1'),
    ordertotal: new FormControl('')
  });

  endpointGet = 'http://localhost:3000/api/personnes';
  endpointPost = 'http://localhost:3000/api/personne/';

  getPersonnes() {
    return this.http.get(this.endpointGet);
  }
```

While I'm writing this question, I found this answer : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53112864/11295075

And I added this to the html :  [hidden]="!listData.data" matSort

It became : `<mat-table [dataSource]="listData" [hidden]="!listData.data" matSort>`

Now when I click it **sorts** but not correctly and here is the error in the console : 
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined**

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkvHI.png)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line

```
    this.listData.sort = this.sort;
```

from `ngAfterViewInit` to when you actually have `listData`. That is, after the return and processing of `getPersonnes()`. That is, here:

```
    this.service.getPersonnes().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.personne = data;
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.personne);
      this.listData.sort = this.sort;
    });
```

Regarding the `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`, easy fixed with the safe navigation operator.

In `<mat-table [dataSource]="listData" [hidden]="!listData.data" matSort>`, change it to `[hidden]="!listData?.data"`. This way it'll only try to access `listData.data` when `listData` is defined.

Comment: Thank you, no error now displayed. But when the sort is not organized, it's randomly mixed. do you have any idea ?