# How to apply custom sorting with API response's data in mat-table?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have tried to add custom sorting in mat-table with API response data. But not getting proper result.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z15qth?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

I tried to add custom sorting as take reference from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550621/problem-sorting-with-matsort-with-api-data), but using this my search functionality is affected and sort is also not working.

How to add custom sorting on mat table header?

Comment: Does [this](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples) works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MatSort only works with MatTableDataSource (not with Arrays).

Some like

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.attendeeList);
```

If you need work with arrays, you need add the event `(matSortChange)` to your [matSort](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api#MatSort)

```
    <table ... matSort (matSortChange)="changeSort($event)">

  changeSort(sort:Sort)
  {
    
    this.attendeeList=this.attendeeList.sort((a,b)=>{
      const value=a[sort.active]>b[sort.active]?1:a[sort.active]<b[sort.active]?-1:0
      return sort.direction=='asc'?value:-value 
    })
    this.attendeeListData = this.attendeeList;
    this.attendeeListTable.renderRows();
  }
```

NOTE: remove the ngAfterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.attendeeList.sort = this.sort;
}
```

And declare your list as `any[]`

```
attendeeList: any[] = [...}
```